# How do I wire a Rasberry Pi 3B+ to a WS2812b RGB strip?

Tags: raspberry-pi, level-shifting, logic-level, sparkfun, ws2812b

I am working on a project where I need to use a WS2812b RGB strip. I am really worried because I have already burnt 2 Raspberry Pis with my wiring. I just want to show my schematics, and be assured as to whether they are correct or not.

I am using a Sparkfun Level Shifter to convert the Raspberry Pi's 3.3V data signal into 5V (used for the WS2812b strip). I am very new to working with hardware (I am more used to software), so please go easy on me.

Here are the schematics, one in visual form, one in a more blueprint-ish form. PLEASE NOTE that the power supply (which is 12V) is not in the schematics. This is because I have already taken care of it (it works and all the lights turn white when it is plugged in).

[image: wiring diagram 1]

[image: wiring diagram 2]

Comment: Can you tell us what burnt?  Did you burn out the 3.3V regulator on the RPi?  You need to keep the 12V away from the logic signals, 12V will fry everything.

Comment: @Mattman944 I provided 12V to the RGB strip only, it didn't get to anything else